# Serializer Error

Tags: c#, serialization, private, public

I have custom class with following properties:

```
Class Person
    readonly public string Name;
    readonly public string FamilyName;
    readonly public string UserName;
    private List<Person> Team = new List<Person>();
    public Person Leader { get; private set; }
    public bool HasTeam { get; private set; }
```

I am getting error on serializer because "Object has **Leader** property that has no public set." However I need to keep it private, as change of **Leader** will cause errors. Do you know any way around? Or I need to make it public and keep in mind that I cannot set it?

Thank you,
Michael

Comment: `[XmlIgnore()]` might be a possibility, but you are really not offering a lot of info here :)

Comment: But this way it will skip it on save/load. :( I simply need to save Person object on close and load on open.

Comment: Then the XmlSerializer might not be what you are after, do you have to save it to XML, or could you use for eg: the BinaryFormatter instead (which serializes the full object instead?). Another (bad) option might be to check upon setting the Leader if it wasn't set yet, in this case set, and when set, throw an error (which would require a private Person leader to verify if it's not set yet)

Comment: @Icepickle `BinaryFormatter` is not intended for persisting data, if the AssemblyVersion changes for any object you will not be able to de-serialize. `BinaryFormatter` is intended for IPC use within the same computer only.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thx for the info :) I was just searching around for options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as mentioned, you could make it so, that it's it can be set only once, but i wouldn't see it as a good option (maybe you should rather rethink how you would like to store this information?)

```
public class Person
{
    private Person leader;
    public Person Leader
    {
        get
        {
            return leader;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Object.Equals(leader, value))
            {
                return;
            }
            if (leader != null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Leader can be set only once!");
            }
            leader = value;
        }
    }
}
```

this would allow you to save/load the values, and it wouldn't allow it to be set afterwards. However, this is just working around the problem.

In case you don't have to save it specifically to XML, you could use a binary formatter, that saves the entire Person object (no matter if it contains private fields / properties)